# Implementing Facebook with parse and method is deprecated

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parsing, deprecated

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44640/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-1)

and tried to add this :

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}
 z
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

> 'handleOpenURL:' is deprecated

I looked this up and surprisingly couldn’t find any solutions. What can I put instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html#//api/name/handleOpenURL%3a) I found recommends using [[FBAppCall handleOpenURL:sourceApplication:withSession:]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBAppCall#handleOpenURL%3asourceApplication%3awithSession%3a) If the tutorial is using outdated code, you may come across more problems so I recommend finding a newer one.

Using this method in your code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I also have found a newer tutorial

Comment: @user3140511 can you please share the new tutorial, thanks. sadly even the Parse.com latest sample app has this outdated call

Comment: In case it is still helpful, @A.Adam look at the doc [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html) in the **Class Methods** section in relation to `handleOpenURL:`. The document is dated 2015-02-20.